# How can i resolve these errors got in VS Code for running a java code in JADE platform

Tags: java, agents-jade

```
import jade.core.Agent;
import jade.core.Runtime;
import jade.core.Profile;
import jade.core.ProfileImpl;
import jade.core.behaviours.*;
import jade.lang.acl.ACLMessage;
import jade.lang.acl.MessageTemplate;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.instance();
    Profile p = new ProfileImpl();
    AgentContainer container = rt.createMainContainer(p);
    
    try {
        AgentController seller = jade.core.container.createNewAgent("Seller", SellerAgent.class, null);
        seller.start();
    
        String[] buyerArgs = new String[]{"A"};
        AgentController buyer1 = container.createNewAgent("B1", BuyerAgent.class, buyerArgs);
        buyer1.start();
    
        buyerArgs[0] = "B";
        AgentController buyer2 = container.createNewAgent("B2", BuyerAgent.class, buyerArgs);
        buyer2.start();
    
        buyerArgs[0] = "A";
        AgentController buyer3 = container.createNewAgent("B3", BuyerAgent.class, buyerArgs);
        buyer3.start();
    
        buyerArgs[0] = "B";
        AgentController buyer4 = container.createNewAgent("B4", BuyerAgent.class, buyerArgs);
        buyer4.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

public class BuyerAgent extends Agent {
    private String requestedProduct;
    private String sellerName;
    private List<String> purchasedProducts = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void setup() {
        // Get the requested product name as an argument
        Object[] args = getArguments();
        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            requestedProduct = (String) args[0];
        }

        // Add the behavior to request the product from the seller
        addBehaviour(new RequestProductBehaviour());
    }

    private class RequestProductBehaviour extends OneShotBehaviour {
        public void action() {
            ACLMessage message = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
            message.setContent(requestedProduct);
            message.addReceiver(sellerName);
            myAgent.send(message);

            // Wait for the seller's response
            addBehaviour(new PurchaseResponseBehaviour());
        }
    }

    private class PurchaseResponseBehaviour extends SimpleBehaviour {
        private boolean receivedResponse = false;

        public void action() {
            MessageTemplate mt = MessageTemplate.MatchPerformative(ACLMessage.INFORM);
            ACLMessage message = myAgent.receive(mt);
            if (message != null) {
                // Product was available and was sold to this buyer
                purchasedProducts.add(requestedProduct);
                receivedResponse = true;
            } else {
                block();
            }
        }

        public boolean done() {
            if (receivedResponse) {
                System.out.println(getLocalName() + " purchased: " + purchasedProducts);
            }
            return receivedResponse;
        }
    }
}

public class SellerAgent extends Agent {
    private int itemsA = 2;
    private int itemsB = 2;
    private List<String> buyers = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void setup() {
        // Add the behavior to handle product request messages
        addBehaviour(new HandleRequestBehaviour());
    }

    private class HandleRequestBehaviour extends CyclicBehaviour {
        public void action() {
            MessageTemplate mt = MessageTemplate.MatchPerformative(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
            ACLMessage message = myAgent.receive(mt);
            if (message != null) {
                String product = message.getContent();
                String buyerName = message.getSender().getLocalName();
                ACLMessage reply = message.createReply();

                if (buyerName.equals("B3") && product.equals("B")) {
                    // Seller cannot sell product B to buyer B3
                    reply.setPerformative(ACLMessage.FAILURE);
                    reply.setContent("Not allowed");
                } else if (product.equals("A") && itemsA > 0) {
                    itemsA--;
                    reply.setPerformative(ACLMessage.INFORM);
                    buyers.add(buyerName);
                } else if (product.equals("B") && itemsB >
                0) {
                    itemsB--;
                    reply.setPerformative(ACLMessage.INFORM);
                    buyers.add(buyerName);
                } else {
                    reply.setPerformative(ACLMessage.FAILURE);
                    reply.setContent("Not available");
                }

                myAgent.send(reply);
            } else {
                block();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void takeDown() {
        System.out.println("Seller " + getLocalName() + " sold to: " + buyers);
    }
}
```

This code gives me errors below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        The method instance() is undefined for the type Runtime
        Profile cannot be resolved to a type
        ProfileImpl cannot be resolved to a type
        AgentContainer cannot be resolved to a type
        AgentController cannot be resolved to a type
        jade cannot be resolved
        AgentController cannot be resolved to a type
        AgentController cannot be resolved to a type
        AgentController cannot be resolved to a type
        AgentController cannot be resolved to a type

        at Main.main(main.java:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency problem, your project cannot find Jade and its associated classes.
You should add Jade using maven so that your IDE can update the missing libraries.

**Repository to add to your pom**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Dependency to add to your pom**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gitlab.jade-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>jade</artifactId>
    <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

See : https://jade-project.gitlab.io/page/download/